# Angular form: what is the different between submit event and click event?

Tags: angular

I'm wonder what is the different between form submit event and button click event to do the http post action.

Form submit example:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
  <input name="last" ngModel>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Button click example:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
  <input name="last" ngModel>
</form>

<div>
  <button (click)="onSubmit(f)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

In background, the handling is just the same.

```
  @ViewChild(NgForm) f: NgForm;

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.f);  
  }
```

Anyone know what is the difference?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is they are two different events registered to different elements in the DOM.

> The [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) event fires on the `<form>` element itself, and not on any `<button>`
>   .The submit event only fires when the user clicks a submit button

**By default your submit button has a type of `type="submit"`**

On the other hand the [click](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event is fired when the user clicks on an element, in this case your button.

Answer (score 2):

One of the differences that i know so far, is that if you are inside a `ngForm` and if you have a `(ngSubmit)` event, the function that is linked to this event will be executed if you press **ENTER** key. 
This is helpfull to go through forms quickly, without touching the mouse.

There are more info on the subject at this address 
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Yes, just the same that answered by @Narm

Comment: Yes, i replied before him though... Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

There is no flagrant difference between the two. The answer made by @HMarteau is inaccurate however, as you can use the 'Enter' button to submit an Angular form whether using the `ngSubmit` or the `click` event.

The main difference is that Angular's `ngSubmit` allows you to use some powerful built in properties such as `required`, `max-length`, etc., used for validation, which you might not be able to use in the case of `click`.

Comment: Um, you are right, but I can using the FormGroup to do the validation what if using click event. Anyway, thank you as well.